# Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL While `ng build` in Angular

Tags: angular, build

While Running `ng build --prod` or `ng build` in angular project i got this error

[image]

any idea how to resolve this ?

PS: I have already changed the version of angular-cli to `1.2.6` from `1.2.3`, still not working.

After googling i found this is issue of security with chrome browser, but how to solve this i am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

1. cd project-dir
2. delete node_modules and package-lock.json
3. npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
4. npm cache clean --force
5. npm install @angular/cli -g
6. npm cache verify
7. close console and open new console session
8. cd project-dir
9. npm install
10. ng --version (result : 1.4.2)
11. ng build --prod

it worked successfully

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try it later.